# javascript-библиотека с поддержкой RSA

Tags: javascript, rsa

Необходима проверенная js-библиотека, обеспечивающая реализацию RSA-шифрования с наличием следующего функционала:

- генерация пар ключей
- шифрование на открытом/закрытом ключах
- расшифровывание на закрытом/открытом ключах
- представление открытого/закрытого ключа и результата шифрования в виде строки (Base64 и прочее)

Построение API может быть, например, аналогично проекту https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js

Comment: а что мешает реализовать свое? "свое" в шифровании не есть хорошо, но т.к. это js, то как бы хорошо не было написано - всегда можно будет это обойти. Может поделитесь зачем вам это? А вообще, можете посмотреть на [эту библиотеку](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/), вроде должна подойти

Comment: @BOPOH *всегда можно будет это обойти* - даже если подразумевать браузерный жс, т.е. с открытым исходным кодом, то диффи-хеллмана третье лицо все равно не разгадает. Если вы про возможность внедриться в виртуальную машину, то тут вообще все на свете бесполезно, у чего есть дебаггер.

Comment: @Etki, попробуйте использовать дебаггер для апача ) а алгоритм диффи-хафмана разве применим для канала, где можно модифицировать данные? А если https, то зачем шифрование?

Comment: @BOPOH да дебажьте на здоровье https://httpd.apache.org/dev/debugging.html

Comment: @Etki, чтобы дебажить - надо же чтобы апач был готов для этого? т.е. скомпилирован с нужной опцией, запущен с нужными ключами и т.д. Правда, если есть доступ, ничто не мешает подготовить его, только будет ли это соответствовать исходным целям? Но писал я про браузерный js. Систему может сломать как тот, кто открывает страницу, так и тот, кто встал между сервером и браузером, т.к. раз не https, то можно браузеру послать что угодно (хотя бы просто подменив js-ку на нужную). Только если ставить какой-нибудь модуль для браузера, чтобы стойкий вариант диффи-хеллмана использовать

Comment: @BOPOH gdb/strace даже без debugging symbols может что угодно размягчить, даже другой процесс gdb.  Я, впрочем, все равно не понимаю, что здесь доказывается. Стойкого варианта диффи-хеллмана не существует; против ma-in-the-middle атак существует система иерархии сертификатов, для приложения это может быть просто pre-shared secret.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32551/discussion-between-bopoh-and-etki).

Comment: @BOPOH Эту библиотеку я собственно уже и использую для DES, но там нет RSA. Написать свою мешает чисто отсутствие времени на это - RSA на C я реализовал еще в 1994, но повторять этот геморрой на js на старости лет как-то не хочется. Что касается безопасности, то ясен пень, что по-хорошему надо все делать на апплетах, но надо очень по-быстрому сделать межплатфоменный функциональный прототип.

Comment: Господа, есть ли схема обмена ключами, неуязвимая для атаки MITM? Примерно знаю принцип работы схем обмена на основе квадратичных полей, когда передается идеал кольца целых, но даже эти схемы, вроде бы, уязвимы. Наверно, если бы неуязвимых схем не было, то Диффи-Хеллман не использовался бы повсеместно?

Comment: @typemoon диффи-хеллман тоже mitm'ится

Comment: Ну так я знаю, что mitm'ится, поэтому и интересуюсь, есть ли что-то лучше. Похоже, что у всех этих алгоритмов фундаментальная уязвимость в том, что информация передается через канал связи, к которому можно подключиться. И никакая алгебраическая теория от этого не спасет.

Comment: @typemoon без pre-shared secret - никак, mitm такой же полноценный собеседник, как и настоящий.